# Removing hidden recessed faucet aerator

Tags: faucet

I have a TRINITY Stainless Steel Utility Sink that came with a faucet   like this one:  https://trinityii.com/stainless-steel-utility-sink-nsf-with-faucet/

I need to remove the aerator so I can hook up a portable dishwasher adaptor.  I tried to find a key online that would fit but can't seem to find one that has the same hole pattern.  I sent a message to Trinity but have gotten no response yet.  Anyone know what key and where I could purchase it?

I tried to remove it by sticking a couple of nails up into it and twisting counterclockwise... it gave a little but seems to just possibly be spinning and not advancing outward.  Any advice?

[image]

[image]

Comment: the aerator is not necessarily removable

Comment: That just seems completely bonkers... that an aerator would not be removable.  :/

Comment: What happens when it gets full of crud?  Just toss the whole faucet?

Comment: yes, it would be crazy, but not unheard of

Comment: You said you tried a couple of nails...just by themselves?  I would drive a few nails through a thin piece of wood—try to match the aerator pattern—and use the wood as a knob.

Comment: Good idea about using the wood to make my own key... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manufacturer's video collection, there is a tiny seam at the "tip" of the faucet where the whole tip should unscrew from the outside.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ6e4EaBIlc

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VO-lwKuqfo

[image: Screenshot of animation]

They also refer to a "free app" that might or might not have more info.  I didn't try that yet but could have some potential.

Comment: Well I'll be dab nabbed.  That seam was totally invisible. Thanks so much!!!